# BlackBerry - Possible to Hide Video Field?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, camera, flashlight

I want to write an application like a Flashlight (with the help of the camera LED).

```
Player player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?encoding=video/3gpp");

player.realize();

VideoControl videoControl = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
if(videoControl != null)
{
    videoField = (Field)videoControl.initDisplayMode( VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE, "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field" );
    try
    {
        videoControl.setDisplaySize(1, 1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        PGLogUtil.logString(e.toString());
    }
    videoControl.setVisible(true);
    add(videoField);

    FlashControl flashControl = (FlashControl)
            player.getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.FlashControl");
    setFlashlight(true);
}
player.start();
```

The code above works perfectly, but I want to hide the `videoField`. When I removed `add(videoField)` or use `videoControl.setVisible(false)`, the flashlight does not work. Can someone explain why?

How I can turn lights on with a hidden `videoField`?

Comment: What minimum OS do you have to support?

Comment: maybe try pushing another screen to the foreground, or when you extend MainScreen override paint and dont do anything there.

Comment: Hi CAMOBAP, did you get the solution. I am also facing the same issue here. Can you please help.

Comment: I still haven't a solution for all devices. For some devices line `videoControl.setDisplaySize(1, 1)` working without exception and the camera `Field` successfully hidden

Answer (score -1):

I just got a bb that had a flash i wanted to try my hands on this same issue. I finally got it to work anyway.
On thing i observed during the whole testing time was that if the videoField is hidden like you said, the flash wouldn't work...So the trick i did was

```
    <pre>
    _videoControl.setDisplaySize( 1 , 1 );
    </pre>
```

And that did the job for me. You could as well set it to

```
    <pre>
    _videoControl.setDisplaySize( 0 , 0 );
    </pre>
```

But whatever you do ... ensure you set

```
    <pre>
    _videoControl.setVisible(true);
   </pre>
```

else your flash will not work

Comment: This "answer" is just a repeat of what the question posted.  What new information are you adding?

Comment: @Nate:  He asked how he could hide the video field and i suggested he set the display size of the control...

Comment: you just repeated the **exact** same code that he said he already tried.